# Counting the Repeating of words in a list PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code like:

```
s = "hello this is hello this is baby baby baby baby hello"
slist = s.split()
finallist = []
for word in slist:
    if len(word) >= 4:
          final = final + [word]
```

Basically this code above for taking the list and only putting a list of words that have more than 4 characters.

From this list I want to be able to count the number of times that the same word appears and and save it into a new list. so it would be like [3,2,4] 3 being the times of hello, 2 being the times of this, and 4 being baby.

Comment: I recommend this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @squiguy thank you thats the doc's I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import re

reg = re.compile('\S{4,}')

s = "hello this is hello this is baby baby baby baby hello"
c = Counter(ma.group() for ma in reg.finditer(s))
print c
```

result

```
Counter({'baby': 4, 'hello': 3, 'this': 2})
```

Also:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

s = "hello this is hello this is baby baby baby baby hello"

for w in s.split():
    if len(w)>=4:
        d[w] += 1

print d
```

Comment: @Xaphen ``re`` is the module bringing regexes to our disposal. The pattern ``'\S{4,}'`` means 'any character different of a whitespace' ``\S`` , number of such characters : 4 or more.  Whitespaces are ``\f`` , ``\n`` ,``\r`` ,``\t`` ,``\v`` ,``\x`` and blank. ``re.finditer(s)`` is a generator of matches found in ``s`` that verify the pattern. A match ``ma`` holds inside itself information : ``ma.group()`` is the information consisting of the entire matching portion of ``s`` matching with the pattern

Comment: @Xaphen Thank you. Note that I used ``re.finditer()`` because it's a generator that yields matchings one after the other without having to create a new object before iterating in it as does ``re.findall()``. But if the string isn't gigantic, it may be equivalent to write ``Counter(reg.findall(text))``. If such a research has not to be repeated, and then regex object ``reg`` won't be used again, it's also possible to write directly ``Counter(re.findall('\S{4,}',text))``

Answer (score 4):

`collections.Counter` is clearly your friend (unless you need the output in a specific sorted order). Combine it with a *generator comprehension* to generate all the length-4 words and you are golden.

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(w for w in s.split() if len(w) >= 4)
```

If you need the elements in order of their first appearance, use an ordered dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

wc = OrderedDict()
for w in s.split():
    if len(w) >= 4:
        wc[w] = wc.get(w, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use the `count` method from the slist.

I think you may use a dict to have a better control of

```
s = "hello this is hello this is baby baby baby baby hello"
slist = s.split()
finaldict = {}
for word in slist:
    if len(word) >= 4 and not finaldict.get(word):
          finaldict[word] = slist.count(word)
```

Now, if you want the list of values, just do this: `finallist = finaldict.values()`

Comment: @nneonneo Only use count once per word.

Comment: @FernandoFreitasAlves: so if it is a list full of unique words, then it is really bad :)